# Unable to get header to fall under my menu via Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Working on flexboxes and I'm unable to get my Awesome Logo header to fall underneath the very top menu which includes the date, login, etc

How it should look:

[Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mNzu.png)

How my layout is:

[My Funky Garbage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htkzf.png)

I'm assuming it's something with the formatting of my divs from my .html because after placing the header-container and head classes around differently, the header moves :(

html code:

```
<body>
        <div class='menu-container'>
            <div class='header-container'>
                <div class='header'>
                  <div class='subscribe'>Subscribe &#9662;</div>
                  <div class='logo'><img src='images/awesome-logo.svg'/></div>
                  <div class='social'><img src='images/social-icons.svg'/></div>
                </div>
              </div>    
            <div class='menu'>
              <div class='date'>Feb 7, 2023</div>
              <div class="links">
              <div class='signup'>Sign Up</div>
              <div class='login'>Login</div>
            </div>   
        </div>    
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-container {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5995da;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu {
    width: 900px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.login {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.header-container {
    color: #5995DA;
    background-color: #D6E9FE;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

.header {
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

I'm on the cross axis section of this website: https://www.internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flex-direction: column-reverse;` to `.menu-container`.

For cleaner code you can also get rid of `.header-container` and add its css properties to `header`, change the order of the `menu` and `header` divs, and use `flex-direction: column;`. Like the code below.

```
<body>
    <div class='menu-container'>
        <div class='menu'>
          <div class='date'>Feb 7, 2023</div>
          <div class="links">
          <div class='signup'>Sign Up</div>
          <div class='login'>Login</div>
        </div>
        <div class='header'>
          <div class='subscribe'>Subscribe &#9662;</div>
          <div class='logo'><img src='images/awesome-logo.svg'/></div>
          <div class='social'><img src='images/social-icons.svg'/>
        </div>   
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions! the html answer from Pedro ending up working! I will try of all the replies and note to them for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your .header-container out of .menu-container, so they're sibling elements. If needed, create a wrapper for them.

Your .links div is also unclosed, which might be causing you issues.

So your HTML should look something like this:

```
<body>
  <div class='menu-container'>
    <div class='menu'>
      <div class='date'>Feb 7, 2023</div>
      <div class="links">
        <div class='signup'>Sign Up</div>
        <div class='login'>Login</div>
      </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
  <div class='header-container'>
    <div class='header'>
      <div class='subscribe'>Subscribe &#9662;</div>
      <div class='logo'><img src='images/awesome-logo.svg'/></div>
      <div class='social'><img src='images/social-icons.svg'/></div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</body>
```